# aws_emr_cluster - is it possible to retrieve the instance identifiers

Tags: terraform

I am creating an EMR cluster using the aws_emr_cluster resource in terraform.

I need to get access to the instance ID of the underlying EC2 hardware, specifically the MASTER node.

It does not appear in the attributes and neither when I perform an `terraform show`

The data definitely exists and is available in AWS.

Does anyone know how I can get at this value and how to do it it using terraform?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access the nodes (EC2 Instances) in an EMR Cluster through terraform. It is the same case for AutoScaling Groups too.

If terraform includes EMR or ASG nodes, state file will be changed everytime a change happens in EMR/ASG. So, storing the instance information won't be ideal for terraform.

Instead, you can use AWS SDK/CLI/boto3 to see them.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes sense that dynamic resources are not stored in the state file although it makes it hard to provision resources such as  VPC service interface endpoints that require IP addresses or instance identifiers when setting up the NLB target group.

Another possibility for my problem would be to use a fixed IP (private) address for my master node, this will help when creating the target group. I am not sure if this is possible to do using the EMR cluster resource, what do you think?

Comment: The easy solution in your case would be to import master & nodes after your initial EMR apply. Otherwise, you will end up with Node or Python.